# Count post in a list of category with Mysql & PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database convert from MSSQL. They store their database like that:

- tbl_item (id,channels,name)
- tbl_channels (id,name)

Example:

- item: '1', '1,3,5', 'Item A'
- item: '2', '1,2,6', 'Item B'
- channels: '1', 'Channel A'
- channels: '2', 'Channel B'

How can I count number of item in a channels, i try with "`SELECT item WHERE channels IN (1)`" to count items of Channel A but no success.

Please help me!
Thanks

Comment: Do you by any chance have anything to say about this awfull database design making such queries very complicated while it would be very simple with a normalized database ? If yes, the first thing would be to update the design instead of trying to get something good out of that one...

Comment: Yes, it has been converted to seperate tables. Thanks!

Comment: Good ! This will spare you a lot of trouble (complicated/impossible queries, performance issues, ...) in the future !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very painfully.  You should really convert the database to have an `item_channels` junction table.  This would have one row per item and per channel.  It is a really, really bad idea to store lists in string fields.  The proper way to store lists in a database is using a table.

Sometimes, though, you are stuck.  If this is one of those cases, then use `find_in_set()`:

```
select count(*)
from tbl_items i
where find_in_set(1, i.channels) > 0;
```

Then, after doing that, start working on fixing the database structure.

EDIT:

If you need to count all of the channels:

```
select c.*, count(*)
from tbl_items i join
     tlb_channels c
     on find_in_set(c.id, i.channels) > 0
group by c.id;
```

Then hope that your database is not too big, because performance may be very bad and you'll have no way to improve it (other than by fixing the database structure).